# how to use wordProcessingDocument to load wordopenxml (in string form)

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, visual-studio-2012

So let's say in Microsoft Word VBA I got the openxml string using

```
Dim xmlstring as string = activedocument.range.wordopenxml
```

And now I want to create an wordProcessingdocument using this string.

However, in the relevant webpage (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.packaging.wordprocessingdocument_members(v=office.14).aspx) I cannot find any info about constructing an wordprocessingdocument using a string.

Can anyone teach me how to do this?

Comment: did you try a google search..? if so what were you search parameters..? try this link and click on the VB example or convert the C# example into VB.NET https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478190.aspx

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio or VBA in Word?

Comment: That's not VBA *or* C#

Comment: @MethodMan Yes. I have search the parameter and there is only two types. One asks for the file location while the other one asks for IO Stream

Comment: I am using VIsual Studio and I am designing an addin for MS Word, the constructor cannot use the file that is being used. @Blackwood

Answer (score 0):

A word document is not just an xml file, it's an OPC (Open Packaging Convention), so you can't simply "create the file from xml".

Eric White describe in his blog how to do that : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/transforming-flat-opc-format-to-open-xml-documents.aspx

The principe is to create an empty file and then parse your xml to feed the opc file